# Using php to Auto generate C++ code

Tags: php

SCROLL DOWN if you just want to see the question without much explanation

I have kind of a big application with a lot of values that are used as options. The control for the application is a website, application itself is C++ and all the options are stored inside MySQL so that both C++ and php can access it.
So I am using php to read bunch of values from a text file, and auto generate SQL, C++ and php code, since the options are used everywhere and are so massive that it would take too long to implement them, and would be too much of a hassle to add an extra options in the future.

This is what one line of my text file looks like

```
`input_video_standard`|:|INT|:|NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'|:|profile->input.videoStandard|:|Video Standard|:|SD 576i@50Hz (B,G/PAL)|:|SD 480i@59.94Hz (NTSC)|:|HD 720p@50Hz|:|HD 720p@59.94Hz|:|HD 1080i@25Hz|:|HD 1080i@29.97Hz
```

Once I read in that line I use

```
$pieces = explode("|:|", $line);
```

This part is for generating C++ code now
I have an array called variables, where I store name of the variable for C++ and what type it is.

```
$variables[] = array($pieces[1], $pieces[3]);
```

Once I loop through the text file and gather up all the data

I try to create a string which I will later on store inside a text file

```
$cpp .= "memset(prof,0,sizeof(prof));\n";
$cpp .= "sprintf(prof, \"CALL put_into_input(%d, 'test'";
for($i = 3; $i<count($variables); $i++)
{
    if(strpos($variables[0], "VARCHAR") === FALSE)
    {
        $cpp .= ", %d";
    }
    else
    {
        $cpp .= ", '%s'";
    }
}
$cpp .= "\nprofile-".">"."pfile";
for($i = 3; $i<count($variables); $i++)
{
    $cpp .= ",\n".$variables[1];
}
$cpp .= ");\n";
```

**THE QUESTION**

The problem is that when I try to concatenate string *profile->input.videoStandard* to my main string it simply saves it as Array, and I have noticed that php does not like -> as a string in general, which is why I used *"-".">"* wherever I could. How do I go about getting php of accepting -> as a string?

Thanks to anyone for their help.

Comment: How do You concatenate the string?

Comment: I use . to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have noticed that php does not like -> as a string in general.

Nothing wrong with a `->` in a string.

Unless there is some `$` in there too.

This will cause PHP to think you are trying to access a property of an object instance.

E.g. `$object->something`. You could just use single quotes in stead of double quotes to prevent PHP trying to parse the string. Other than that there shouldn't be any problem using `->` in a string.

**EDIT**

You're code looks strange to me.

You are doing `$variables[] = array($pieces[1], $pieces[3]);`

which is the same as `$variables = array(array($pieces[1], $pieces[3]));`

So you only have `$variables[0]` and not `$variables[1]`

Comment: Thank you very much, that has worked! But what about reading in the string from a textfile? I can not control whether it has double or single quotes. So how would I go around that? The string being read in is still being displayed as Array instead of profile->input.videoStandard

Comment: @Quillion: Have you changed all your double quotes to single quotes around your string in your PHP file?

Comment: Yes every single one besides newline character, so if I want a newline character I do this ');'."\n"; but other than that every single one is a single quote. But my string that is being faulty is stored inside $variables[1] which I read from the text file, and I concatenate it like this $cpp .= ','."\n".$variables[1]; could this be the problem?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($variables[1])` or `print_r($variables[1]);` and report the result?

Comment: I did that. when I print the value of $pieces[3] it says profile->input.videoStandard When I do $variables[] = array($pieces[1], $pieces[3]); Then do print_r it shows that it is an array that has INT or VARCHAR for first value and "" for second. Does the string somehow dissapear?

Comment: in PHP you don't have to add `[]` to make it an array. `$variables = array();` will do just fine. In fact, if you're using `$variable[] = 'x';` you are actually saying that `$variable` is already an array and you're pushing another value. PHP syntax is very different from C and you have to understand that.

Comment: Yes I do understand it and I do want to add an array to an array. $variables is a two dimensional array. It contains a list of variables that will be used the C++ code generation. And the only way I know of when I want to add an array to an array is using $variables[] = array(); I love php :D thanks for all your help, I shall be trying to continue debugging this weird phenomenon

Comment: @PeeHaa You are completely right man, sorry for messing up so horribly. I just realized that I was supposed to call variables[$i][0] and $variables[$i][1], I feel like a disgrace of a programmer for wasting two days to figure this out. Sorry if I wasted your time too.

Comment: @Quillion: hehe No problem. It happens sometimes to all of us :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, variables within **double** quotes are parsed.

```
$var = "hello";
$str = "This is a variable: $var";

// The value of $str will be "This is a variable: hello"
```

When you use **single** quotes variables are not parsed.

```
$var = "hello";
$str = 'This is a variable: $var'; // Please note the single quotes here

// The value of $str will be "This is a variable: $var"
```

I think in your case, the `->` are recognised as variables because that's the syntax used for object-oriented programming to get both properties and methods.

```
$object->property;
$object->method();
```

Personally I use single quotes whenever I don't need my string to be parsed for variables or regular expressions.

[Single quote strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

[Double quote strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score -2):

You could use apostrophes intead of quotes maybe ?